Big decimal values getting expanded when using copy activity in ADF using REST API as source
I am trying to copy data from a system using copy activity.My source is REST and my sink data format is JSON.Data is stored in ADLS .
When big  decimals are getting copied the decimal is getting expanded- for example if decimal is 155575307.6085215 then in ADLS i could see it as 155575307.60852146
similar examples
source->5.6982967562685
destn->.5.69829675626848
It is not happening for all values but it happens for randomn values.
I could not use schema mapping here as it is common pipeline which takes data from multiple rest sources and stores in ADLS.
Can anyone help in understanding why this happens when using REST API as source.

According to this it is a limitation in copy activity. So, you can use mapping data flow to copy data from Rest API to ADLS. It takes the value as in the source without expending decimal value as shown below in source:

According to this if decimals with precision greater than 28 (BigDecimals) then convert the datatype of column to string using toString(<ColumnName>) expression in derived column as shown below:

